# ACML 5.3.1 on Intel Core i7-3770 Segment Error

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, intel, intel-mkl

Yesterday, I want to test cblas_dgemm example, but I have encountered the problem: [How to link Intel MKL library, just cblas_dgemm function is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19117880/2495287)
, it still exists. So I test the dgemm using ACML 5.3.1 library.
The demo example is from http://r2labs.org/pct/Scott_McAllister_work/pCT/acmlg0.1/win64/examples/time_dgemm_c/dgemm_c_example.c, But when I link the project with `-L/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/ -lacml`, it can compiled successfully. But it has an error when running :

```
    ACML example: C dgemm test
    -------------------------------------------------------

    ACML example: DGEMM call
    --------------------------------------------------------------

    Matrix A:
      1.6416   1.4190   1.2844   1.6736 
      1.5516   1.8641   1.5513   1.2102 
      1.2852   1.2583   1.2804   1.3271 
      1.3752   1.4440   1.5300   1.0118 

    Matrix B:
      1.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000 
      0.0000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000 
      0.0000   0.0000   1.0000   0.0000 
      0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   1.0000 
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Plz, help me.Thank you.

Comment: You could modify your tag since it is about ACML but not MKL

Comment: Yes. I know it. But there is no tags about "ACML", and I have no enough money to create the new tag. So,...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to set OMP_NUM_THREADS befor excuting you program.

```
EX)
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=10
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've set it. I usually set it in environment variable.

Comment: This problem looks like have no answer. Somebody posted a qustion on the ACML Froum.[link](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/169180)